# Color table row based on variable value

Tags: php, css

I have a table which I fetch with jQuery from a database.
I would like to color each row based on one the value that a specific column has. Example I have column "status".
I want the row yellow if in that row the status is "progress".
I want the row red if in that row the status is "cancel"

I have tried with a class but that color the entire table,
I thought about using a variable color which will change the tr but not sure how to do that.

```
<style>
        .yellow {
            background-color: darkred;    
        }      
</style>
    
<tbody>
<?php
include ('connection.php');
            

$sql = $link->query('SELECT * FROM job');
            while($data = $sql->fetch_array()) {

                    echo '
                    

<tr class="yellow">
                        <td>'.$data['id'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$data['number'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$data['date'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$data['device'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$data['model'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$data['problem'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$data['status'].'</td>
          

          <td>'.$data['assigned'].'</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
        ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use inline style. I'm guessing that you have a 3rd status option of success, which will be green.

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');
$sql = $link->query('SELECT * FROM job');
while($data = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    $color = $data['status'] == "cancel" ? "red" : ($data['status'] == "progress" ? "yellow" : "green");
    echo '
        <tr style="background-color:'.$color.'">
            <td>'.$data['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['number'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['date'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['device'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['model'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['problem'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['status'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['assigned'].'</td>
       </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: that worked smooth. Thank you. I did not know the usage of "?" and ":" inside the variable.

Comment: Its name is [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be, to write the following in your css:

```
.bg-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

and than in PHP:

```
echo "<table>";
if ($data["status"] === ["expected_value"]) {
    echo "<tr class='bg-yellow'>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["status"] . "</td>"; // and so on
    echo "</tr>";
} else {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["status"] . "</td>"; // and so on
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I hope, it helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you set the background color in your Style tag or CSS file it works global but you can use inline css like this here:

```
<?php
    require('connection.php');
    $sql = $link->query('SELECT * FROM job');
    while($data = $sql->fetch_array()) {
        if ($data['status'] == 'cancel') {
            echo('<tr style="background-color:red">');
        }
        else {
            if ($data['status'] == 'progress') {
                echo('<tr style="background-color:yellow">');
            }
            else {
                echo('<tr style="background-color:green">');
            }
        }
        echo('
            <td>'.$data['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['number'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['date'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['device'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['model'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['problem'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['status'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['assigned'].'</td>
        </tr>
        ');
    }
?>
```

or you gave an sepcial class to the row if the status is progress.

This is an example and I hope it helped you a bit.

Comment: @HTMHell used the short version of my code. It could be a performance buff.

Comment: @e-r-a Shows you the version if you want to use a CSS File or you want to config your style in a Style tag.

Comment: I didn't use your version of the code. (How could I, if I answered before?) Anyway, it's defiantly not about performance. It's about how readable is your code. Messy `if` and `else` with is less readable than a variable assignment in a one-liner.

Comment: I know xD I always thinking in ```if``` and ```else``` so I didn't came to your solution xD all three versions we wrote are posible and dosn't use much performance. Switch Case is possible aswell but not the best is i guess so xD That's why I upvotet yours.

Answer (score 0):

My solution below is largely along the lines of what was posted earlier. However, doing it this way will give you a little more control over the semantics and color contrasts, when you want to take accessibility into account. You generally wouldn't want to pair 'black' with 'darkred' as your example seems to do. This code is also a little more concise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
td
{
        padding: 0.5em;
}
.color-bg-green
{
        background-color: green;
}
.color-bg-red
{
        background-color: red;
}
.color-bg-yellow
{
        background-color: yellow;
}
.color-bg-orange
{
        background-color: orange;
}
.color-fg-white
{
        color: white;
}
.color-fg-black
{
        color: black;
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
<?php

$rowData = [];
$rowData[] =
['id' => 1, 'number' => 123, 'date' => '2020-01-01', 'device' => 'Smartphone', 'model' => 'Galaxy', 'problem' => 'Lorem ipsum', 'status' => 'success', 'assigned' => 'Person A'];
$rowData[] =
['id' => 2, 'number' => 123, 'date' => '2020-01-01', 'device' => 'Smartphone', 'model' => 'Galaxy', 'problem' => 'Lorem ipsum', 'status' => 'failure', 'assigned' => 'Person B'];
$rowData[] =
['id' => 3, 'number' => 123, 'date' => '2020-01-01', 'device' => 'Smartphone', 'model' => 'Galaxy', 'problem' => 'Lorem ipsum', 'status' => 'success', 'assigned' => 'Person C'];
$rowData[] =
['id' => 4, 'number' => 123, 'date' => '2020-01-01', 'device' => 'Smartphone', 'model' => 'Galaxy', 'problem' => 'Lorem ipsum', 'status' => 'pending', 'assigned' => 'Person D'];
$rowData[] =
['id' => 5, 'number' => 123, 'date' => '2020-01-01', 'device' => 'Smartphone', 'model' => 'Galaxy', 'problem' => 'Lorem ipsum', 'status' => 'processing', 'assigned' => 'Person E'];
$rowData[] =
['id' => 6, 'number' => 123, 'date' => '2020-01-01', 'device' => 'Smartphone', 'model' => 'Galaxy', 'problem' => 'Lorem ipsum', 'status' => 'success', 'assigned' => 'Person F'];

foreach ($rowData as $data)
{
        switch ($data['status'])
        {
                case 'success':
                {
                        $rowFgColor = 'white';
                        $rowBgColor = 'green';
                }
                break;
                case 'failure':
                {
                        $rowFgColor = 'black';
                        $rowBgColor = 'red';
                }
                break;
                case 'pending':
                {
                        $rowFgColor = 'black';
                        $rowBgColor = 'yellow';
                }
                break;
                default:
                case 'processing':
                {
                        $rowFgColor = 'black';
                        $rowBgColor = 'orange';
                }
                break;
        }
        echo "<tr class=\"color-fg-$rowFgColor color-bg-$rowBgColor\">";
        foreach (['id', 'number', 'date', 'device', 'model', 'problem', 'status', 'assigned'] as $column)
                echo "<td>{$data[$column]}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```